# Spring Security - Weird errors

Tags: security, spring, tiles

All,

I am trying to add Spring Security(3.0.7) to my web application(Spring 3.0.6, Tiles 2.2).  The default <form-login/> works as expected, but I can't create a custom one that does. Some issues encountered:

1. Every time a user clicks on the login link, the login page gets called twice
2. The UserDetailsService throws an Exception if the user doesn't exist, but the exception never gets picked up anywhere and used.  This causes the <form-login/> to reroute to the login-page instead of the authentication-failure-url
3. I never see error messages when logging in with a bad username (This may be due to the previous issue mentioned above)
4. After a successful login, sometimes it will open to the correct page, other times it will randomly open up a javascript file that was being referenced inside the page.

I've followed all the tutorials out there and cannot come up with anything working.  Does anyone happen to know the class responsible for creating the default login?  Perhaps I can look at the source code and mimic what they have.

Has anyone experienced weird behavior like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out 2 of my issues.  I'm posting them in case anyone else has the same thing happen.

For #1/#4: The site was using tiles, and a default html header block was used throughout the site.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript">
 </head>
```

The configuration explicilty blocked this javascript file for users who were not logged in.

```
    <intercept-url pattern="foo.js" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

So when a user came to the home page, the site would load except for foo.js.  Since the methods in foo.js never get called before logging in, everything seemed to work fine.

However when someone tried to log in, Spring Security saw foo.js as the first protected page to show, and automatically opened it up.

This also caused the login page to be called twice.  Once for the actual login link, and once for the foo.js file.

Comment: I also figured out Issues 2 and 3.  I forgot to add my login failure page to the 'allowed' list, so it always rerouted to the regular login page.  <intercept-url pattern="/loginFail" access="permitAll" />